# Cross-Platform, Multi-Rig Workflows

Tags: platform, workflow, mac, windows

I myself have three systems for working with sound, a MacBook Pro/Mbox for mobile recording and editing, a Windows 7/Digi002 LE workstation at home for smaller, more personal projects and access to a Mac Pro HD suite for larger projects. I find that I lose a significant amount of time and productivity moving between workstations.

If you're in a similar situation, what kinds of tools (software or otherwise) are you using to bridge the gap between Mac OS, Windows and/or Linux, as well as between multiple rigs?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not running into these issues, since I'm on Macs only (and honestly do very little work at hoem anymore), but here's how I would tackle this if I wanted to move across the multiple platforms.

1. Play to the lowest common denominator you'll be working with regularly.  If you're on LE, keep your session under the 32 track limit, 48 if you've got any of the toolkit bundles.
2. "Save As" to the lowest version number of Pro Tools you'll be working with if you're on a more recent version on a different computer.
3. Work with RTAS plug-ins unless your on the HD system and are in finishing mode. Also, if there's a TDM version of an RTAS plug-in on your system, you can just click the TDM option on the plug-in window to convert it once you're on the HD system
4. .WAV files only
5. As long as your working with 7.3 and higher, keep the files on an external drive that is formatted in Mac HFS+.  As long as all of the files associated with the session are on that drive, your PC based Pro Tools system will have no issues working with it.  Then your Mac computers are obviously covered as well.
6. Carry your iLok from one system to another. That's partly what it's designed for.

Those should eliminate a bulk of the problems you might encounter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just have multiple rigs because you have multiple locations.

Here at work I use a PC and a Mac for audio editing/design.  I actually have to perform a 180 in my chair to work on each station.  I do most of my design work on the Mac with a Pro Tools HD system and I do a lot of smaller editing and source grabbing on the PC with Sound Forge and Soundminer.  I don't find it slows me down much but if you're having to travel to multiple locations in order to do work then yea, I can see that being an impediment.

The biggest problem it sounds like you might have is if you do work on your HD rig and try and bring it home.  That might just be something you need to consider before you come home (how to bounce things down and what plugins you use that will be compatible with your home setup).